# Are there any downsides to using very very very large bit flags (aside from memory)

Tags: javascript

I realize that bit shifting is handled in 32 bits, but I realized that (at least with modern browsers), I can declare pretty massive numbers - ie:

```
console.log([
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
].join('\n'));
```

Appear valid and correct.  I've tested performance on this, and it seems to be much much faster than any boolean operation, so I'd like to move to this method -- however, I'm a little weary of using huge numbers since I've never seen anything like this before.  Do you see or have you run into issues using huge bit flags?

Performance benchmark here: http://jsperf.com/bitwise-v-property-access/3

Comment: The main downside I personally see is poor code readability.

Comment: What could you possibly need that many flag bits for???

Comment: You've really only got 52 (or is it 53? that always confuses me) bits to work with, which is 13 F's.  Also, you have to be careful because lots of bitwise operations in JavaScript further truncate to 32 bits.

Comment: I wouldn't be using shifts, just and/or ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  numbers in your array are not 'valid and correct'. They overflow the 32 bit boundary, so they are converted to IEE754 64 bit doubles, so they loose precision when too much digits are set.
You cannot use such figures to perform your operations i fear.

Edit : the output of your code is  (on latest Chrome/mac OS) :

(as you can see in this fiddle : http://jsbin.com/OQiCAhUk/1/ )

```
"18446744073709552000
7.922816251426434e+28
3.402823669209385e+38
1.461501637330903e+48
6.277101735386681e+57
2.695994666715064e+67
1.157920892373162e+77
4.9732323640978664e+86
2.13598703592091e+96
9.173994463960286e+105
3.940200619639448e+115
1.6923032801030364e+125
4.542742026847543e+133
1.2194330274671845e+142
3.273390607896142e+150
8.78694100496718e+158
2.3587265155134633e+167
6.331658277711476e+175
1.6996415770136547e+184"
```

so it seems even the second number is already out of bounds.

Comment: I should have said "appear".  You are correct.  The & op fails.